# How to do logistic mixed regression with these data?

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model

In this study, measurement was done on each subject at 3 time points (0, 4 and 80 hours). Each subject was then checked for some event. The data is in following form:

```
Subject    Time    Value   Event
     1       0h      100     Yes
     2       0h       55     Yes
     1       4h       54      No
     2       4h      116      No
     1      80h      117     Yes
```

Question is whether higher (or lower) value is related to occurrence of event?

Since this is repeated measurement, it will have to be mixed regression. Since outcome is binary, logistic regression is needed.

How do I analyze above data?

**Edit:** To clarify the role of time: `Value` may be related to time. Amount/level of `Value` affecting `Event` may vary with time. Hence, lower `Value` may lead to event at time 0 than at later time. Hence, time affects value and value affects events. Time does not directly affect events. How can this be incorporated in analysis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have enough subjects then a logistic linear mixed model should work in this scenario. Eg:

```
glmer(Event ~ Value + (1|Subject), data = mydata, family = binomial(link=logit))
```

The estimate for `Value` will be the association of a 1 unit change in `Value` with the log-odds of the probablity of the event occuring. You can exponentiate it to get the actual odds.

If time is just the index for repeated measures and isn't of interest then there is no need to include it. You might want to allow for `Value` to also vary accross sujects with

```
glmer(Event ~ Value + (Value|Subject), data = mydata, family = binomial(link=logit))
```

Comment: What is the difference between (1|Subject) and (Value|Subject) since there is no other predictor variable?

Comment: Also, time may affect value. How can that be detected?

Comment: If time affects value and the proability of the event then it is a connfounder and you should include it in the model as a fixed effect. If it does not affect the event then you should exclude it.

Comment: I have seen it being used at some places as `(1|time/subject)` or `(1|subject/time)`. What is that for?

Comment: That would be where time is a factor and either subjects are nested within time (`(1|time/subject)`) or time measurement are nested within subjects (`(1|subject/time)`).  If time affects value - AND  the event - then you could try  the 2nd model, or just include time as a fixed effect.

Comment: Number of subjects is 200. Is it "enough"?

Comment: Yes 200 is plenty :)

Comment: Role of time is important though complex. I have tried to clarify in my question above.

Comment: Please be more specific Are you saying that time affects value directly but only affects the event through value, OR it also affects the event directly. It can only be one or the other.

Comment: Time affects Value directly. Value affects Events. No direct relation of Time to Events. Also, each subject has had measurements done at 3 time points.

Comment: OK in that case, it should not make a difference to the estimate whether time is included or not - but it may make reduce the precision, so I would stick with the simpler model and exclude it. The repeated measures are handled by the random intercept for subjects, but if you are concerned, you can also fit random intercepts for the subject:time interaction - if the variance is estimated close to zero then you can remove it,.